# Operations of a group on a set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've been reading Algebra (Revised Third Edition) by Serge Lang these days.

Proposition 5.1. says "If $G$ is a group operating on a set $S$, and $s\in S$, then the order of the orbit $G_s$ is equal to the index $(G:G_{s})$ "

Proposition 5.2. says "The number of conjugate subgroups to $H$ is equal to the index of the normalizer of $H$ "

In particular, in proposition 5.1., when $G$ operates by conjugation on the set of subgroups, and $H$ is a subgroup, we can get that the number of conjugate subgroups to $H$ is equal to the index $(G:G_H)$. $G_H$ is equal to the normalizer of $H$, also.

What makes me confused is that it seems to be different from the proposition 5.2.
Am I wrong?

Comment: How is this different from Proposition 5.2? They seem to be in perfect harmony, even by what you write.

Comment: I mean why the index of (G:$G_H$) and the index of the normalizer of H are the same.

Comment: In future, don't use MathJax just to write a single symbol in an expression. Instead, if an expression is a mathematical one, always write the whole thing. So, don't write `s$\in S$` (resulting in "s$\in S$") but instead write `$s\in S$` (resulting in $s\in S$). Also, write names of mathematical objects in mathjax, so you have a group $G$, not a group G. Makes it far easier to read.

Comment: @Hsiung If I understand your question correctly, then the reason they're the same is because the normalizer of $H$ is precisely the set of elements $g$ for which $gHg^{-1}=H$, which is exactly the set $G_H$, since this is equivalent to fixing $H$ under the conjugation action.

Answer (score 0):

You have 
\begin{align*}
G_H &= \{ g\in G \mid gHg^{-1}=H \}
    \\ &= \{ g\in G \mid gH=Hg \} = N_G(H),
\end{align*}
so $G_H$ is indeed the normalizer $N_G(H)$ of $H$ in $G$. The first equality is simply by definition of the action: It is by conjugation.

Answer (score 0):

What may be confusing you is the notation $G_s$. This is a subgroup of $G$, call the *stabilizer* of the element $s \in S$, that is:

$G_s = \{g \in G: g\cdot s = s\}$.

In the case where $G$ acts on the set $S = \{H: H\text{ is a subgroup of }G\}$ by conjugation, we have:

$g\cdot H \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} gHg^{-1}$

so the stabilizer of a subgroup $H$ is all $g \in G$ such that $gHg^{-1} = H$.

This is the same set (as another answer shows) as the normalizer of $H$ in $G$, $N_G(H)$.

In other words, with a group action (or "operation" as your text says), we think of each group element $g$ inducing a function $S \to S$. Then $G_s$ is the set of all elements of $G$ who have $s$ as a "fixed point" of the induced function.

This often gives a "new way" to look at some group constructions which occur frequently.